# winform setup proejct, how to bundle .net frame work 4 and Crystal reports dependencies?

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0, crystal-reports, setup-project

I have developed a small application and want to make its setup. Is it possible I can bundle .net framework 4.0 and crystal report dependencies with it. So that user may have not to install it seprately ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on your setup project
Select properties the from the pop window select Prerequisites.
From the list select .NET Framework 4.0 and SAP Crystal Reports Runtime Engine.

Select "Download Prerequisites from the same location as my application" from the radio button group.

This will out put the installers for your dependencies along with your setup.

Comment: thanks @Geethanga. Can you please also guide how I shoudl give path to downloaded files ? I try to run the application and got the error:

The install location for prerequisites has not been set to 'component vendor's web site' and the file 'Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\CRRuntime_32bit_13_0.msi' in item 'SAP Crystal Reports Runtime Engine for .NET Framework 4.0' can not be located on disk. See Help for more information. D:\hotdesk\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\backup\Setup\Setup.vdproj Setup

Comment: it did not automatically detect installers from my machine. I tried to put on root and also inside setup project but still error were there.

Comment: Do you get two additional installers for Crystal Reports and .NET Framework along with your applications installer?